# Google Calendar v3 Java API: Insert event

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

I am trying to insert an event into a google calendar via the java API:
[CalendarTest](https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/documentation/calendar/v3/java/latest/index.html)

I would like to run:

```
new Calendar.Events.Insert(calendarId, content).execute();
```

except that the constructor is protected and I cannot find a static public
method to do the insert. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue as follows:

```
calendarClient.events().insert(appCalendarId, calendarEvent).execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes by creating object of google's Event class's type and then calling various methods for adding event to calendar :-

```
Event event = new Event();
event.setStart(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(start));
event.setEnd(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(end));
event.setSummary(eventEntity.getSummary());
event.setLocation(location);
event.setDescription(description);
```

after that calling following code to insert the event

```
calendarService.events().insert(appCalendarId, calendarEvent).execute();
```

here the calendarService is generated from google's credentials that we get after successful response from google api

Comment: To insert an event you need 'calendarId' i.e. a Calendar identifier. To retrieve calendar IDs call the calendarList.list method. If you want to access the primary calendar of the currently logged in user, use the "primary" keyword.

`calendarService.events.insert("primary", newEvent).execute()`

Comment: yes correct, "primary" is the default calendar so specifying it is like going to create event that way

Comment: Can I ask where "calendarService"? What request generated it?