# Can't insert multiple events in Google Calendar

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, calendarcontract

In my application i'm using the CalendarContract API to manage calendars and events on the Google Calendar. I'm having some problems when adding multiple events to a single calendar. In general, the problem of this method is that whenever i add a new event to the google calendar, the old event is replaced by the new one. Here is the code of my method:

```
    public int addEvent(Context context, String color, int calendarId, String name, String location, String description, Date dateBegin, Date dateEnd) {
            long startMillisEpoch;
            long endMillisEpoch;

            Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            beginTime.setTime(dateBegin);
            startMillisEpoch = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();

            Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            endTime.setTime(dateEnd);
            endMillisEpoch = endTime.getTimeInMillis();

            int eventColor;
            try {
                eventColor = Color.parseColor(color);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Get a random color
                Random random = new Random();
                eventColor = MyApp.RANDOM_COLORS[random.nextInt(MyApp.RANDOM_COLORS.length)];
            }
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, calendarId);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startMillisEpoch);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endMillisEpoch);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, name);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, location);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, description);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_COLOR, eventColor);
            // NOTE: Every event MUST have a timezone. Otherwise,
            // the application will throw an IllegalArgumentException
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName());
            // Put default values
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY, NON_ALL_DAY);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.GUESTS_CAN_INVITE_OTHERS, 1);
            Uri calUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
            if (calUri != null) {
                try {
                    return Integer.parseInt(calUri.getLastPathSegment());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
```

Any ideas for solving this kind of problem? Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

According the [API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) i guess you're missing `.execute()`

```
Uri calUri = context.getContentResolver()
                    .insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values)
                    .execute();
```

Also [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16587138/google-calendar-v3-java-api-insert-event)

Comment: Sorry for my unexperience, but the Uri class does not have any method "execute". Thanks for your answer, first of all.

Comment: are you sure you need to use `Uri` and not `Event`? Did you checked the related api and questions?

Comment: I'm using CalendarContract to allow local calendars. That's what i need in my case.

Comment: Another thing. There is any known-issue of the google calendar app or the CalendarContract API that if we add an event title with too many characters, that same event is added to all days of the event month?

I added an event with a small amount of characters and an event with a large amount of characters. That "bug" didn't happen for the first case. Weird stuff.